# How do I transform a Div thats inside another Div using transform-origin?

Tags: html, css, drawing

So this question is a little more nuanced than in the title. I'm trying to create sort of animated character, and since it's my first time drawing with CSS, I was wondering how I'd program a sort of joint.

I've got a div that's the arm and another div that's the forearm that's within that first div so that the arm acts as the parent. So far everything works, I rotate the arm and the forearm follows. However, when I attempt to rotate the forearm, things get weird. I figured I could use transform-origin to locate the pivot point and things should work.

Any help appreciated! :)

PS. I've linked my codepen [here](http://codepen.io/mobyfreerunner/pen/Wpybex)

```css
.arm {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: green;
  transform-origin: top;
}
.arm .foreArm {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: translateY(160px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arm">
  <div class="foreArm"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need this?

```css
.arm {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: green;
  transform-origin: top;
}
.arm .foreArm {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  transform-origin: 50% 185px; /*left=50%, top= 185px = 200px - border-radius/2*/
  transform: translateY(160px);
  animation-name: myRotate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes myRotate {
    0%   {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    
    100% {transform: rotate(135deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="arm">
  <div class="foreArm"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OH Wow! thank you so so much! This was EXACTLY what I needed. I guess I was using transform-origin wrongly. I'm not too sure I understand what the % is for. Does that mean the new origin is in the middle of the object? I think I understand the part that you commented out. Thank you SO Much!

Comment: @MubarakMarafa `transform-origin` is the point at which the object rotates(the axis of rotation). E.g. a ceiling fan has `transform-origin: 50% 50%` or `transform-origin: center center`. And This bar http://www.spaceflight.esa.int/impress/text/education/Images/Circular_Motion/Image_023.png has `transform-origin: 0 50%` or `top 50%`